# bash: return exit code from function and print out from her, but not the exit code

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a function like this

```
function backup {
  do_backup
  printf "success"
  do_more_backup
  echo "success"
  if ... ; then
    echo 1
  else
    echo 0
  fi
}
```

And I have a conditional statement like that

```
if [[ ! $(backup) ]]; then
...
```

I can't get the output from function into the shell, but it's evaluating all commands - I've checked in debug mode. I want to evaluate the function, so it does her purpose and in a meanwhile print out some log messages, then to check on exit code of this function if everything succeed. How to approach this problem in bash? And how to avoid printing out last echo, which is a status, or an exit code of a function for evaluation purposes in conditional statement.

Comment: The `[[`... `]]` is entirely superfluous here. The correct and idiomatic syntax (once you change `echo` to `return`) is simply `if ! backup; then`...

Comment: I don't have much experience with bash, thus I make this errors. Thank you tripleee for guiding me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please use `return 1` `return 0` not `echo`

Comment: The question isn't very clear but I guess this is the correct answer.

Comment: On behalf of [Szymon Błaszczyński](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5608228): *and change conditional statement to if ! backup; then* is also needed.  You can add comments to your own question.  They are better than editing the answer as people will double check it makes sense.